# Keep Getting <property object at 0x000001F7E7FE6F70>

Tags: python, discord

```
import lightbulb
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests

plugin = lightbulb.Plugin('Images', 'Create Images')

@plugin.command
@lightbulb.option('user', 'who to create image of',required = True)
@lightbulb.command('slap', 'Slap someone')
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def wanted(ctx: lightbulb.context, user = hikari.User):
    
    slap = Image.open('images\slap.png')
    userAvatarUrl = user.display_avatar_url
    response = requests.get(userAvatarUrl)
    pfp = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

    pfp = pfp.resize(100,100)

    slap.paste(pfp,(120,120))
    slap.save('Profile.jpg')

    await ctx.respond(file = hikari.File('Profile.jpg'))    



def load(bot):
    bot.add_plugin(plugin)
```

I am trying to fetch the user's avatar url but I keep on getting <property object at 0x000001F7E7FE6F70>. I am using Hikari and Lightbulb for this project. I have checked the documentation and tried to figure it out but nothing seems to work.

**Full Traceback**:

```
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\env\lib\site-packages\lightbulb\app.py", line 1038, in handle_message_create_for_prefix_commands
    await self.process_prefix_commands(context)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\env\lib\site-packages\lightbulb\app.py", line 1010, in process_prefix_commands
    await context.invoke()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\env\lib\site-packages\lightbulb\context\base.py", line 311, in invoke
    await self.command.invoke(self)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\env\lib\site-packages\lightbulb\commands\prefix.py", line 119, in invoke
    await self(context, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\env\lib\site-packages\lightbulb\commands\base.py", line 605, in __call__
    return await self.callback(context, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\extensions\Fun\images.py", line 17, in wanted
    response = requests.get(userAvatarUrl)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 484, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 368, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 439, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '<property object at 0x000001F7E7FE6F70>': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://<property object at 0x000001F7E7FE6F70>?

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\discord bot\env\lib\site-packages\lightbulb\app.py", line 1057, in handle_message_create_for_prefix_commands
    raise new_exc
lightbulb.errors.CommandInvocationError: An error occurred during command 'slap' invocation
```

Comment: From the stack trace, it seems that the value of `userAvatarUrl` is not a string, so, when you pass it to `requests.get(userAvatarUrl)`, the method tries to use it as a string, which causes the error. Try to inspect the value of `userAvatarUrl`, to see what it is.

Comment: <property object at 0x0000015EFF546E30> By printing it it gives  this value. [Im sorry im new to coding]

Comment: This is an object of the `property` class; it probably has its own properties and methods that you could access.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have supplied I can see that you defined `user` as an argument to the command function. This is not how options are passed to the command function by default (if you add `pass_options=True` to the `@lightbulb.command` decorator then this would work though).

By default command options are stored in an attribute on the context - [`Context.options`](https://hikari-lightbulb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_references/context.html#lightbulb.context.base.Context.options). In this case, you would retrieve the user object using `ctx.options.user`.

By supplying the argument in the command function and having it default to the `hikari.User` class, when you call `user.display_avatar_url`, you are just returning the property object attached to the class, not an actual `User` object.

To fix your code you should do one of the following:

Use `ctx.options.user` instead of an argument in the command function

```py
@plugin.command
@lightbulb.option('user', 'who to create image of', type=hikari.User)
@lightbulb.command('slap', 'Slap someone')
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def wanted(ctx: lightbulb.context):
    ...
    userAvatarUrl = ctx.options.user.display_avatar_url
    ...
```

Or add the `pass_options` argument to the `@lightbulb.command` decorator

```py
@plugin.command
@lightbulb.option('user', 'who to create image of', type=hikari.User)
@lightbulb.command('slap', 'Slap someone', pass_options=True)
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def wanted(ctx: lightbulb.context, user: hikari.User):
    ...
```

**Important:** Note how I added a kwarg `type=hikari.User` to the `@lightbulb.option` decorator - this ensures that lightbulb converts the option into a `User` object before calling your command function. If this was omitted, then the option would be a string, not a `User` object.

**N.B.** you are using the synchronous HTTP library `requests` here which will block your bot while the request is running. You should instead use an async library such as `asyncio` (included when you install hikari) which will allow other commands to run while the HTTP request is in progress.